# Change div class of object depending what slide is showing onscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a website which has a slideshow. I would like to change the div class of an element depending on which slide is currently being shown. Unfortunately, I am a complete novice when it comes to Javascript and all my attempts to get something working so far haven't worked (presumably because I'm missing something which is horrifically basic). Does anyone know how would be best to get it to work / could anyone write a basic bit of javascript which would let me do this to get me started?

---

The code controlling the slideshow:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

---

My painfully novice attempt to get this working:

```
if (slideIndex = 1) {
  document.getElementById("bgcol").className="bga";
}

if (slideIndex = 2) {
  document.getElementById("bgcol").className="bgb";
}
```

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison. `===` additionally checks the type. You're looking for `if (slideIndex == 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your if statements inside function `showSlides(n)` (and don't forget to change `=` to `==` in  them)